# How to reduce width of div using JQuery, CSS so that the left section is reduced and not the right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This sounds like a stupid question but I cannot figure an easy way of doing it. Let us say that I have a fixed-width Div with the string ABCDEFGHIJ as its content. If I reduce the width it will stop showing HIJ or whatever from the right side. I want the visibility of the content from the left side getting impacted. So, let's say that the div has a width of 100px, then

```
$(div).css('width':'50px');
```

should not impact the display of EFGHIJ, for example.

Yes, I could  have an inner div and shift its position to the left, for example, by the amount of width reduced. Is there a shorter way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: samir, you should be putting relevant code for problem you are having.

Comment: check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3J3vD/).. You are looking for `direction: rtl` I suppose.

Comment: @Milind AnantwarI think the code I have shown is enough. Reducing a width of a div reduces it from the right. I want it to be reduced from the left, from a content-perspective. No code is required but I just provided one statement for clarity.

Comment: @Mr_Green. Exactly. That's what I was looking for! If you can upgrade that to an answer, I would like to accept it. Upvoted for now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Hide the beginning letters but not the last letters, you need to change the direction of the letters using css `direction: rtl`.

and also to hide the letters, you should mention `overflow: hidden` and some width to the container.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3J3vD/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a wrapper and CSS positioning:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/aJHv5/)**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">ABCDEFGHIJ</div>
</div>
#outer {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #999;
    width:50px;
    height:20px;
}
#inner {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```